# How do I select distinct columns together with the count of records they have

Tags: sql

How do I select distinct columns together with the count of records they have like if i have this data:

```
  banana
  apple
  orange
  banana
  apple
  apple
```

and I want it to display this:

```
  |banana|2|
  |apple |3|
  |orange|1|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) Clause.

```
SELECT `fruitname`, COUNT(*) as `totalCount`
FROM `tableName`
GROUP BY `fruitName`
```

Comment: Amazing that we have the same column name ang table name and letter case only that you have added backticks around it. Good job

Comment: Thanks @JohnWoo! Yeah, just noticed.

Answer (score 5):

Make use of *aggregate* function like `COUNT()` and a `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT fruitname, COUNT(*) totalCount
FROM tableName
GROUP BY fruitName
```